# What will be the value of strlen(str)- 1 in a 'for' loop condition when str is empty?

Tags: c

I am analyzing a scenario:

```
char str[] = ""; // Understand
```

If I understand `strlen(str)`, it comes out to be 0. This is OK.

```
printf(" %d,  %ul,  %u, %d,  %ul, %u", 
    strlen(str),
    strlen(str),
    strlen(str),
    strlen(str) - 1,
    strlen(str) - 1,
    strlen(str) - 1);
```

Output is:

> 0, 0l, 0, -1, 4294967295l, 4294967295

I understand these as well.

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str) - 1; i++)
{
}
```

Here I don't understand what the value of `strlen(str) - 1` would be in the `for` loop condition.

`strlen(str) - 1` is giving the value 4294967295 in the for loop.
Why is that? Why not -1?

Comment: Afraid of debugger? Try stepping!

Comment: I step in as well. In gdb if I do p strlen(str)-1  this will give me an int value. M just trying to understand as a condition what is the value in the for loop. I checked strlen(str) is 0 even in for loop condition. strlen(str)-1 is 4294967295... why is this happening?

Comment: Check which result type `strlne` actually returns. Then read in the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) how that type behaves on underflow (hint: it is _well defined_). Then you can answer your question yourself. Note: `i` has the wrong type!

Comment: Your code contains undefined behaviour. The result of `strlen` has type `size_t` but you print it using contradictory formatting specifiers. The proper formatting specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`.

Comment: strlen() returns a size_t, which is an unsigned int.  Your compiler will raise a warning about comparison between signed and unsigned value.  As always, your compiler is right.   Your specific implementation is allowing wraparound/underflow in the negative direction.  wraparound/underflow is one of the things considered as undefined behaviour.  As always, with undefined behaviour, anything can happen.

Comment: @user3629249  "wraparound/underflow is one of the things considered as undefined behaviour" is true with signed integers, but not here.  Since the return type of `strlen()` is `size_t`, an unsigned integer, wraparound/underflow is well defined and **not** undefined behaviour.

Comment: I guess your "analysis" doesn't include reading the man page for `strlen`. *... 4294967295 I understand these as well* -- really? That's not consistent with not understanding why `strlen(str)-1` is 4294967295.

Comment: Four upvotes for what is, essentially '0-1'??

Comment: @JimBalter: Pfft, that's nothing. (S)he also includes the output of both `%u` and `%ul`, apparently without noticing that `%ul` is just `%u` followed by `l`.

Comment: @MartinJames There are **5** upvotes. I learned long ago that SO votes and rep are not a rational reflection of anything.

Comment: The `printf` statement causes undefined behaviour, you should not try to deduce or claim any understanding based on its output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement

```
printf(" %d,  %ul,  %u, %d,  %ul, %u", strlen(str),strlen(str),strlen(str),strlen(str)-1,strlen(str)-1,strlen(str)-1);
```

shows that when `strlen( str ) - 1` is outputed like unsigned integer for example using format specifier  `%ul` its value is `4294967295l`

In the condition of the loop

```
for (int i=0;i<strlen(str)-1;i++)
```

the compiler has to determine the common type of the left and right operands that to determine the type of the result of the condition

```
i<strlen(str)-1
```

The right operand `strlen(str)-1` has type `size_t` (the return type of function `strlen` is `size_t`). It is unsigned integer type usually that corresponds to `unsigned long`. It can not have negative values. Any value that stored in an object of this type is interpretated as a non-negative value and as the output shows the value of `strlen(str)-1` is equal to `4294967295l`. (The actual value you could get if you used type specifier `%zu` because it may not be excluded that `size_t` can correspond even to unsigned long long)

The right operand has type `int`. Its rank is at least not greater than the rank of size_type. So the both operands are converted to type `size_t` and have non-negative values.

This procedure of determining of the common type is called the usual arithmetic conversions.
It is obvious that `4294967295l` is greater than 0. Thus the loop will iterate `4294967295l` times if it does not have a break statement.

You could get the expected result if you rewrite the condition in the loop the following way

```
for ( int i = 0; i < ( int )strlen( str ) - 1; i++ )
```

Comment: What is the lower-case `l` for in `4294967295`

Answer (score 16):

`strlen` returns `size_t` which is an unsigned integer. So `strlen(str)-1` would produce `SIZE_MAX` (the maximum value `size_t` can hold) if `strlen(str)` is `0`.

You should be using `%zu` to print `size_t` values.