# Why does the 'for' loop condition fail?

Tags: c, type-conversion, c-preprocessor, implicit-conversion

In the code shown below, nothing gets printed, which means the condition in the `for` loop fails. What could be the reason?

I'm wondering because when I print `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` separately, it gives `5`, so naturally this must be `5-2=3 => -1<=3`, so it should print something.

```
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))

int array[] = { 23, 34, 12, 17, 204, 99, 16 };
int main()
{
    int d;

    for (d = -1; d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2); d++) {
        printf("%d\n", array[d + 1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain this code?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361713/what-will-be-value-of-strlenstr-1-in-for-loop-condition-when-str-is-empty-in/31361751#31361751

Comment: "Because when I print TOTAL_ELEMENTS separately, it results in 5" - No, it does not. Any reason you make it that complicated?

Comment: I don't know which compiler you use but GCC gives you the proper hint: "warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer". If you have switched on all warnings, of course. Who gave this 8 (in words: eight!) upvotes?

Comment: @deamentiaemundi That warning only comes up with `-Wextra`.  Not everyone uses it, but everyone should.

Comment: @dbush comes up with `-W`, too,  for GCC 4.8.5. But that*s with GCC and there are many more C-compilers out there, of course.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi GCC's `-W` and `-Wextra` are two names for the same mode.  Back in the day, there was only `-W`; at some point, I don't remember exactly when anymore, the devs decided that `-Wextra` was a better name, but `-W` is kept around for compatibility with old makefiles.  This will also apply to any compiler that tries to be drop-in command-line compatible with GCC, e.g. clang and icc, but *not* cl.

Comment: What is the reason for starting the for loop at -1 and then add 1 into the array index?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is a result of the "usual arithmetic conversions".

From section 6.3.1.8 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is
>   needed.
>
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have
>   unsigned integer  types,  the  operand  with  the  type  of  lesser 
>   integer  conversion  rank  is converted to the type of the operand
>   with greater rank.
>
> Otherwise,  **if  the  operand  that  has  unsigned  integer  type  has 
>   rank  greater  or equal  to  the  rank  of  the  type  of  the  other 
>   operand,  then  the  operand  with signed  integer  type  is 
>   converted  to  the  type  of  the  operand  with  unsigned integer
>   type.**
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
>   represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type, then the  operand  with  unsigned  integer  type  is 
>   converted  to  the  type  of  the operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise,   both   operands   are   converted   to   the   unsigned 
>   integer   type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed
>   integer type.

The `sizeof` operator returns a `size_t`, which is an unsigned value.  So `(sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])) - 2` is also unsigned.

Because you are comparing a signed and an unsigned value, the signed value is converted to unsigned.  Converting -1 to unsigned results in the largest unsigned value, which results in the comparison being false.

If you cast the right hand side to `int`, it will work as expected.

```
for(d=-1;d <= (int)(TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);d++)
```

Output:

```
23
34
12
17
204
99
16
```

Or you could avoid the issue by normalizing how you index the array:

```
for (d = 0; d < TOTAL_ELEMENTS; d++) {
    printf("%d\n", array[d]);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

When I try to print `TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2` like this:

```
printf("total %d\n", TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2);
```

I got an warning (using gcc 4.8) saying:

```
test.c:8:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("total %d\n", TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2);
  ^
```

The warning means that `TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2` is `long unsigned`. Now when you compare a `signed int` with `unsigned int`, that signed int is treated as unsigned. So in `d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2)`, `d` becomes a very high valued positive number (assuming 2's complement number system is used).

You can cast the result to `int` to fix the issue.

`d <= (int)(TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2)`

Or if you are using the macro in many places then you can change that like this:

```
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (int)(sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
```

This evaluates to an `unsigned` type. In your loop, however, `d` is a `signed` value. In an expression where a signed and unsigned value participate, the signed value is converted to an unsigned. But `d` is -1, which cannot fit in an unsigned, so it "wraps around" to the highest unsigned value on the machine (on 2's complement).

Answer (score 3):

As already explained by other answers, the cause are usual arithmetic conversions, the type size_t obtained using `sizeof` causes int to get converted to unsigned type corresponding to type size_t.

I would like to add that the behavior is implementation defined<sup>1</sup>. The loop can be taken or not. This depends on the definition of the type size_t.

C Standard permits that type size_t has a lower rank than type int. In that case  integer promotions promote the type size_t to type int. At that point both sides have the same type int, so the conversions stop. The comparison `d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2)` then yields true, and the loop is taken.

---

<sup>1</sup> The program is therefore not strictly conforming as the output relies on implementation-defined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You know #define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])) returns an unsigned number, and -1 may become the largest number, because it converts to a unsigned number.

And you can test the expression "printf("%d\n", -1 < TOTAL_ELEMENTS);"; it prints 0. So we can solve by adding (int) before (TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2) or alter the loop:

```
for (int d = 0; d < TOTAL_ELEMENTS; d++) {
    printf("%d\n", array[d]); }
```

And I don't think making the `d` variable dependent is a good way, because `d` is a variable in `for` loop.